# RE split multiple arguments | (or) returns none python

Tags: python

I'm using the RE expression in python and trying to split a chunk of text by period and by exclamation mark. However when I split it, I get a "None" in the result

```
a = "This is my text...I want it to split by periods. I also want it to split \
by exclamation marks! Is that so much to ask?"
```

This is my code:

```
re.split('((?<=\w)\.(?!\..))|(!)',a)
```

Note that I have this (?<=\w).(?!..) because I want it to avoid ellipses. Nevertheless, the above code spits out:

```
['This is my text...I want it to split by periods', '.', None, ' \
I also want it to split by exclamation marks', None, '!', \
' Is that so much to ask?']
```

As you can see, where a period or exclamation mark is, it has added a special "None" into my list. Why is this and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following:

```
re.split(r'((?<=\w)\.(?!\..)|!)', a)
```

You get the `None` because you have two capturing groups, and all groups are included as a part of the `re.split()` result.

So any time you match a `.` the second capture group is `None`, and any time you match a `!` the first capture group is `None`.

Here is the result:

```
['This is my text...I want it to split by periods',
 '.',
 ' I also want it to split by exclamation marks',
 '!',
 ' Is that so much to ask?']
```

If you don't want to include `'.'` and `'!'` in your result, just remove the parentheses that surround the entire expression: `r'(?<=\w)\.(?!\..)|!'`

Comment: Giving you the checkmark for explaining it thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: Or, it is okay to have the parenthesis but a non-capturing one. Like `(?:)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simpler expression (any period not followed or preceeded by a period) with the outer capturing group around the whole or `|` clause to avoid the `None`, not just the first part:

```
re.split(r'((?<!\.)\.(?!\.)|!)', a)

# Result:
# ['This is my text...I want it to split by periods', 
#  '.', 
#  ' I also want it to split by exclamation marks', 
#  '!', 
#  ' Is that so much to ask?']
```

Comment: He actually had two separate capturing groups, one around the period-but-not-elipsis part and one around the ! part. That meant that each match resulted in `[".", None]` or `[None, "!"]` being inserted in the results, rather than just the "." or "!".

Answer (score 1):

it is happening because after every exclamation mark there's a space character which is returned as `None` here.

You can use filter to remove these `None`'s.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "This is my text...I want it to split by periods. I also want it to split \
by exclamation marks! Is that so much to ask?"

>>> filter(lambda x:x!=None, re.split('((?<=\w)\.(?!\..))|(!)',a))

['This is my text...I want it to split by periods', '.', ' I also want it to split by exclamation marks', '!', ' Is that so much to ask?']
```

Comment: instead of ``lambda x:x!=None``, you can use ``filter(None, re.split(...))``