# Using Python, how do I split on multiple delimiters and keep only one in my output list?

Tags: python, regex, split

a very green python user here, so go easy on me and the docs haven't helped me understand what I'm missing. Similar to [RE split multiple arguments | (or) returns none python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320231/re-split-multiple-arguments-or-returns-none-python), I need to split a string on multiple delimiters. The above question only allows either keeping **none** or keeping **both** delimiters - I need to keep only **one** of them. Note that the above question was from 2012, so likely a much earlier version of Python that 3.6, which I'm using.

My data:

```
line = 'APPLE,ORANGE CHERRY APPLE'
```

I want a list returned that looks like:

```
['APPLE', ',', 'ORANGE', 'CHERRY', 'APPLE']
```

I need to keep the comma so I can remove duplicate components later. I have that part working if I could just get the list created properly. Here's what I've got.

```
list = re.split(r'\s|(,)',line)
print(list)
```

My logic here is split on space and comma but only keep the comma - makes sense to me. Nope:

```
['APPLE', ',', 'ORANGE', None, 'CHERRY', None, 'APPLE']
```

I've also tried what is mentioned in the above linked question, to put the entire group in a capture:

```
re.split(r'(\s|(,))',line)
```

Nope again:

```
['APPLE', ',', ',', 'ORANGE', ' ', None, 'CHERRY', ' ', None, 'APPLE']
```

What am I missing? I know it's related to how my capture groups are set up but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a matching approach with

```
re.findall(r'[^,\s]+|,', line)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePjN4n/1). The `[^,\s]+|,` pattern matches

- `[^,\s]+` - one or more chars other than a comma and whitespace
- `|` - or
- `,` - a comma.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/W83zk1):

```
import re
line = 'APPLE,ORANGE CHERRY APPLE'
l = re.findall(r'[^,\s]+|,', line)
print(l) # => ['APPLE', ',', 'ORANGE', 'CHERRY', 'APPLE']
```

Comment: @J-T Splitting with a regex containing capturing groups almost always leads to empty strings or None items in the output, thus, whenever possible, it is advised to use a matching approach, especially when you have such straight-forward requirements.

Comment: Wow, definitely works a lot better. My lack of experience w/ regex is likely my biggest hurdle with this one. So re.findall returns the matched results instead of trying to put the data into a list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without using `regex` you can do like this

```
res = [x for x in line.replace(',', ' , ').split()]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['APPLE', ',', 'ORANGE', 'CHERRY', 'APPLE']
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out `None`s:

```
import re
line = 'APPLE,ORANGE CHERRY APPLE'
print([m for m in re.split('\s+|(,)', line) if m])
>>> ['APPLE', ',', 'ORANGE', 'CHERRY', 'APPLE']
```